# Redirect to SSL/HTTPS

Tags: vb.net, ssl, asp.net-3.5

I have a site where users must only be able to access the `Login.aspx` page via SSL/HTTPS.

Currently I run something like the following in my `Page_Load()`:

```
If Not (IsSSL) Then
   Response.Redirect("https://" + thisDomainName + "/Login.aspx")
End If
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say without using url re-writing rules or some other http module then no, this is the simplest way to get what you are after.

Seeing as it's only the one page, a more elaborate process would be overkill.

Using the various Request.URL... properties may be better than hard-coding however.

Comment: Thanks Justin, shame theres not a better way of doing it.